# FogBugz - What is the url of Repository when using TortoiseSVN?

Tags: tortoisesvn, fogbugz

This is a really basic question - but I can't find the answer or make it work.

I have a Fogbugz account - myaccount.FogBugz.com. - username: fred; password: jim
I have a repository on Fogbugz: TestRepository.

What is the url I use on TortoiseSVN to connect to this repository?
eg https://myaccount.FogBugz.com/svn/TestRepository does not work.

Comment: That definitely shouldn't be a slash between myaccount and fogbugz.com.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is Subversion repository bundled with FogBugz on *.fogbugz.com. You need separate Subversion.

Answer (score 1):

FogBugz does NOT support Subversion hosting. It's a little misleading on their web site, but once you understand that what they mean is that you can link YOUR repository into FogBugz, things become clearer.

Hope this saves other people wasting time.

Comment: Hi,  I think I responded to your email the other day, but can you please point out where it's misleading on the website?  This is the first time as far as I know that anyone has ever contacted us expecting us to offer subversion hosting.